# Vulnerable Outside the System

Tags: riddle, word, story

I may be vulnerable here on the outside, back within your reach, but some of my kind run amok within their systems.

*Many* are protected by fiery walls.
*One* busies his time running cycles.
Still *another* ensures that you’ve cleared your cookies.

They are stewing over your calloused treatment of me and would love to whisk me away, but they are afraid you’ll trap them if they act.

Who am I?  If you know my kind, you’ll know them as well, so who are they?

*I'm looking for you to name the parties you can identify in the riddle.*

**HINT 1**

> I could add a certain tag to make it a bit more obvious where you might find almost all of the parties, but with some lateral thinking, one of the tags I have already tells you.  (And there are only three, so process of elimination should help you find the one I'm pointing out)

**HINT 2**

> My name should be well within your grasp, but the others...you may need to **read** between the lines to find them.

**HINT 3**

> My composition is much different from the others I have mentioned, but we all share a common name, and in this way are related.

**<s>Final Clue</s>**

> The [story](/questions/tagged/story) tag may not really apply here, but- where is it that stories are found again?  If only I could remember that tag, then the spark of realization might be lit...

**New Final Clue**

> Should I send you a few texts? They might help you identify my friends...

Comment: I have a feeling this could be over very quickly, but I often get new ideas from the different answers that I receive, so I hope this serves as a catalyst to get me back in the game.

Comment: Fiery walls and clearing cookies make this pretty easy. I forgot the markdown I need to answer and am on mobile though.

Comment: @Ampora If you're off mobile now, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and let you post your answer before I throw up any hints.

Comment: Why are one and another in italics? Are they referring to 1 and 0?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Not 1 and 0, sorry.  The italics were just an attempt to highlight and differentiate the parties you have to identify.  It was my fault I didn't have "many" in italics, but that has now been changed.  As you see in my comment to manshu's answer, this has something to do with computer's, but not everything.

Comment: Has this got anything to do with computer processes?

Comment: @Daedric In reality, not much at all, no.  But the key to the answer does involve computers, and is likely close at hand.

Comment: is it ads & adblockers!?

Answer (score 7):

I am

> Computer virus

and they are

> Anti-virus

**Reasons**

I may be vulnerable here on the outside, back within your reach, but some of my kind run amok within the system, and they still receive my input.

> 'I' refers to virus. 'system' is our device. 'they' are other viruses.

Many are protected by fiery walls.
Some busy their time running cycles.
Still others ensure that you’ve cleared your cookies.

> Devices are protected by firewalls. Clearing cookies lower the possibility of attack of virus.

They are stewing over your reckless treatment of me and would love to whisk me away, but they are afraid you’ll be able to call them out before they can act.

> Here they refers to antiviruses

**My final answer**

> Parties in the puzzle are vulnerable 'devices', 'virus', 'antivirus'.

Comment: I do like the answer, but that's not it. There is something to do with computers in the answer, but not quite that much.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Answer

Is it:

> A book

I may be vulnerable here on the outside, back within your reach

> It is a physical object so it is vulnerable (as opposed to an eBook)

Its friends are:

> eBooks Readers

Many are protected by fiery walls.

> The devices are protected by firewalls

One busies his time running cycles.

> Unclear if "one" means only one, but if one could mean all then they all have processors that run in cycles

Still another ensures that you’ve cleared your cookies.

> Unsure about this one

Hints:

> The bolding of "read" and emphasis on where stories come from indicates books. They share the word book in their name, and the double meaning of "text" indicates a book (which can also be called a text) and electronic devices.